# How can I unit test an object that requires an API authorization token?

Tags: unit-testing

I'm trying to write a unit test for an object that communicates with a web service via an authorization token. What's the best way to test for both a "good" token and a "bad" token? I'd prefer not to embed a valid token in the test source itself, as I am planning on publicly releasing the code and I don't want my auth tokens floating around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use mock objects.  Create one that accepts everything as a "good" token and one that rejects everything as a "bad" token.  Then you can pass in whatever arbitrary value you want (even the same value for each) and it will behave the way you want it to.